# Hudson - Stale svn tags in config.xml after changing scm to git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, jenkins, hudson

I am using hudson version 2.2.0
After migrating from svn to git, i noticed that subversion related tags, source code location are not getting removed from the config.xml. (Git related tags are present properly)

If i manually remove the unwanted config, it re-appears once i use the UI (re-save)
Did anybody else face this issue?

Build is not getting affected by this. But we have some perl/python code to update the config dynamically and such scripts need to identify whether the job config is svn or git based. Those are getting affected now, as the config.xml contains both svn and git related tags.

I am talking about the following tag which is no longer relavant to the current job (since it moved to git).

`<scm class="hudson.scm.SubversionSCM">

<locations>

<hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>

<remote> path-to-old-svn-repo

...
</scm>`

Any idea?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If keeping historical build data is not of utmost concern, what happens when you create a new job and configure it to use git from the beginning? Don't copy job configuration, actually create it from scratch

Also, since in your .xml it shows reference to modules, you can try deleting disabled modules. There is a link for that on job main page.

Comment: Agreed. But we dropped this option due to the number of jobs that we have.